# CSS Menu - Nav Bar refuses to highlight parent after selecting child

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, dropdown

I know there are 400 of these threads out there but it seems like everyone's code is a little bit different: I've set up my CSS so that a blue bar appears every time you hover over a page in the navigation, and when that link page is clicked, the blue bar stays over it. I CAN NOT get it to stay over the parent page when I click on one of the links with a drop-down menu. I'm able to get a blue bar to appear inside of the dropdown (lol) but can not get it to stay with the parent at all. I've tried all the ancestor tips, all the menu-current tips, i'm just at wits end. I would be eternally grateful for any help.

```
        /*** ----------------------------CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE SQUARES UNDERNEATH THE NAVIGATION BAR HERE ------------------------------- ***/
    nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.current {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #00BCF2;
        color: #00BCF2;
    }

    /*** THIS WILL PROBABILY GET US TO WHERE WE WANT TO BE WITH ADDING AND HOVERING THE PARENT LINK 



     nav ul li:hover > a, .current-menu-ancestor > a, .current-menu-parent > a {
            background-color: #536f9e !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }
        ***/

    /*** add publications from box site level 1 here ***/
    /**** Dropdown ****/
    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE LOGO OF THE DROPDOWN ARROW ------------------------------ ***/



    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE height OF THE DROPDOWN menu ------------------------------ ***/

    .dropdown{
        padding: 14px 16px 37px 10px;
        background: url('images/dropdown_icon.png') no-repeat 99% 21px;
    }
    .dropdown:hover{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    nav ul ul{
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 1;

    }
    nav ul li:hover  ul{
        display: block;
            opacity: 0.9;


    }
    nav ul li ul li{
        margin: 0;



    }
    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE WIDTH OF THE DROPDOWN MENU ------------------------------ ***/
    nav ul li ul li a{ 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    /*** ----------------------------- CREATE BLUE BARS INSIDE OF DROPDOWN ------------------------------ ***/

    nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover, nav ul li:hover ul li a.current{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
```

As Requested, The HTML I have for my beginning --> header is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>XXXXXX</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass('current');
    }
    <!--END OF HEADER -->
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--========================== L O G O  &   N A V    B A R ============================-->
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="home.html"><img src="images/xylophone.png" alt="YouRock" /></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Founders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">Pipeline</a>
                        <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Phases.html">Phase I / II</a></li>
```

Comment: just so I get it straught, you want the current page to have a blue bar under the menu item ?

Comment: Indeed. So far, what I understand is that when hovering an li of the dropdown (Timeline for instance), you want to display the blue bar on the parent dropdown class (Pipeline for instance). Can you confirm this is the expected behavior?

Comment: @PIIANTOM not when that individual is hovered, but when the link is clicked. So for when Home, About, Portfolio etc, are clicked, the blue bar I have stays underneath them. When I click on a link within my dropdown, I'd like "Pipeline" to have the same blue underline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to check if the active link is inside the dropdown block is to set a class. Also it might be useful to set a class to `<li>` containing `.dropdown` link in order to achieve it easily:

```
<li class="drop-li"><a href="#" class="dropdown">Pipeline</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="timeline.html" class="dropdowned">Timeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="Phases.html" class="dropdowned">Phase I / II</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Now you can highlight the desired parent link like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'dropdowned'){
            $(this).closest('.drop-li').children('a').addClass('current');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    }
}
```

This way it will work no matter how many dropdowns you'll have and what are the names of your links and templates.

Comment: Sorry I don't think that worked either @chem1st,  - just to confirm : So for when Home, About, Portfolio etc, are clicked, the blue bar I have stays underneath them. When I click on a link within my dropdown, I'd like "Pipeline" to have the same blue underline -- with this above scenario, I don't see the bar when clicking on, lets say timeline, for example. Would it be helpful to upload the entire CSS I have?

Comment: I understood what you want and my code do exactly that. Have you done everything correctly?

Comment: can you possibly show me exactly where to implement the $(function) at in the CSS? After which line in the code that I showed above did you add the following - by the way, I'm extremely grateful for your help. I've never experienced a public forum where questions are answered so eagerly - on most forums today questions are met with distasteful mocking remarks - I hope one day to be able to help others after I master my skills a bit more!

Comment: sorry @chem1st I don't mean in CSS i meant in the .js file. I'm not too familiar with j query so all I did was create a new file - here I guess called dropdowned.js but I don't think I'm doing it right. I copied your entire js code and saved as the .js file

Comment: You've accepted my answer, does this mean you've successfully done what you wanted? Yeap, you can insert my answer either in js file or in `script` tag directly in a template

Comment: no just trying to acknowledge taht I'm working on it ! - so I create a javascript file , save it in the main folder of files, call it "downloaded.js" and thats it?

Comment: You already have script block in your template. Simply replace your block with mine and add necessary classes to elements.

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

on the timeline.html and on phases.html put this

```html
<ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Founders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown" class="current">Pipeline</a>
                        <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Phases.html">Phase I / II</a></li>
```

, don't put it on the rest, et violla

Comment: In that case you'll have several dublicates of nav on each "dropdowned page". What if the template name or the navbar will change?

Comment: is the menu dynamic then?

Comment: try` if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.pathname)` as your a links are relative urls, window.location.href returns the full url so will never match the relative urls

Comment: sorry @Billy I don't think this worked - just to confirm : So for when Home, About, Portfolio etc, are clicked, the blue bar I have stays underneath them. When I click on a link within my dropdown, I'd like "Pipeline" to have the same blue underline -- with this above scenario, I don't see the bar when clicking on, lets say timeline, for example. Would it be helpful to upload the entire CSS I have?